# composition vs inheritance in Dart?

Tags: dart

When you google **composition vs inheritance**, you most of the times read something like **prefer composition over inheritance**.

Since we can achieve composition through interfaces and in Dart every class has a implicit interface. That makes me think that everything in Dart is composition and I also was told that we can think that everything in Dart is an interfaces.

This makes me conclude that in Dart we are not attach to same problems of inheritance that other programming languages have with it. Since we can always override methods that we inherited (extends) and we also have mixins.

What's the right mind set when programming Dart?

Should we most of the times use inheritances (extends) and only use composition (implements) when the problem demands it in Dart?

But I think I also read somewhere that when you implement a class you are only creating one object and when you extend a class you are creating multiple objects. Which one is more efficient?

Comment: Composition vs Inheritance is not implements vs extends. Composition means that you have a member A.m that holds an instance of another class B that A delegates to for specific actions instead of A extending B that A makes B's capabilities its own.

Comment: Compostion means **has-a** relationship and Inheritance means **Is-a** relationship. I think these OOP concepts are same for Dart and it's actually like Java. Correct me if im wrong. You can read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260343/why-is-inheritance-generally-viewed-as-a-bad-thing-by-oop-proponents